# An exception occurred during a WebClient request c# wp7 Uri.length very long

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, uri, webclient

The problem is that if I do `Webclient.DownloadStringAsync(Uri)`, while Uri.length very long, I see the error: `An exception occurred during a WebClient request`

At URI for Webclient is a restriction on the length of the links?
What about if the link is very long?

```
WebClient queueItem_client = new WebClient();
queueItem_client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(queueItem_client_DownloadStringCompleted);
            queueItem_client.DownloadStringAsync(execUri);

void queueItem_client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{}
```

In `execUri` link length 2234 characters.

[image]

if `execUri` is composed of about 500 characters, then comes the normal response.
[image]

Comment: Added a screenshot of the error.

Comment: @arsenium: A screenshot of an error is useless.  What is the error type, message, and stack trace of the exception and any inner exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some browsers implement a limit on the URI. See [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url). If at all possible for long Uri's (over 2000 characters) consider changing this request into a Post rather than GET and putting your parameters into the body.

Comment: It's not just browsers which have a limit. Some network hardware (proxy servers, etc.) also have limits. Focusing solely on browser limits can be insufficient in some instances. As you say a correct use of the appropriate method to submit large amounts of data is probably more appropriate than focusing on URI length limits.